# default font in flash as3 stylesheet

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet, which successfully applies itself to any text wrapped with a matching tag, but what I want it to do is apply default formatting to the textfield, which I tried unsuccessfully to do via:

```
* { font-family:Gotham,arial; }
```

where Gotham is a successfully imported font option. How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out - I was doing everything properly, but I was forgetting to add

```
textField.embedFonts = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try switching "body" for your "*" ..?